# ComponentResourceManager.GetObject( "$this.Icon" ) throwing Invocation Exception on WinXP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, icons, windows-xp

This is generated code on a winform app's InitializeComponent() implementation (from the code-behind *.Designer.cs file).

This code works on Vista/7, but on XP it blows up at runtime.

I have a custom Icon added to the form.  It was initially a png file.  Suspecting that XP couldn't handle that format (the inner exception is something about serialization) I changed it to an ico file.  Same result.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added the icon just by pointing it to the ico file, without adding an embedded resource file.  I did that, and now it works.  Odd.  Still would like to know why.

Comment: I had the same problem. It seems that the icon format was causing the problem. If it is "png" icon then it won't work under xp. If it is "favicon" icon then it will work in all cases. In both cases the icon's extension was .ico. I've recompiled my program with the "favicon" icon and now it works under xp too.